# How to ensure NEST connects to Elasticsearch client node

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, connection-pooling, nest, failover

I've configuration as follows:
There are 4 VMs running on machine and each of it runs Elasticsearch instance.

- http://192.168.44.1:9200 has `node.data: false` and `node.master: false` - a dedicated client node.
- http://192.168.44.2:9200 has `node.data: false` and `node.master: true` - a dedicated master node.
- http://192.168.44.3:9200 has `node.data: true` and `node.master: true` - worker node with chance to become master for failover
- http://192.168.44.4:9200 has `node.data: true` and `node.master: true` - worker node with chance to become master for failover

Everything is fine at this point. So question is how would I ensure that my client connects to right node when I'm using this connection string?

```
var node1 = new Uri("http://192.168.44.1:9200");
var node2 = new Uri("http://192.168.44.2:9200");
var node3 = new Uri("http://192.168.44.3:9200");
var node4 = new Uri("http://192.168.44.4:9200");

var _connectionPool = new SniffingConnectionPool(new List<Uri>() { node1, node2, node3, node4 });
var _settings = new ConnectionSettings(_connectionPool, defaultIndex: "testing")
    .SniffOnConnectionFault(false)
    .SniffOnStartup(false)
    .SniffLifeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

I want all of my searches to be performed only using client node (node1) and indexing to be done using worker nodes(node3, node4).

What I've read on [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html) that it's recommended to set `http.enabled: false` for worker nodes so they don't process HTTP requests at all and communication between them is done using *Transport* module. So if I would do that, I would have to reduce my connection pool and connect only to Client/Master node. Is this good design at all?

Or is it better to run local copy of Elasticsearch instance on webserver, set this node as a Client and connect only to it, meanwhile nodes in VMs would be workers(and one dedicated master). But how would I ensure cluster failover then if my local node decides to crash?

Any questions - let me know.

Comment: As per my understanding you want to achieve the index & search to be performed by separate servers am i correct?

Comment: By seperate nodes (each node would sit in seperate VM). But perhaps that's bad design? Feel free to criticize it, I'm open to suggestions. Can we create a chat here and discuss it?

Comment: Yes sure.. how can we create a chat here?

Comment: Can you try this link, please? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78882/elasticsearch-evaldasb